# iOS. Call navigation controller methods within a UIToolbar subclass

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, callback, subclass, uitoolbar

How to perform this better. For example, I have a button in my toolbar which must perform something like this:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Any ideas? Except of:

1)Defining the toolbar and it items inside the UIViewController subclass. It works for current view only.

2)Creating a pointer to navigation controller inside the toolbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you can get access to UINavigationController from appDelegate

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [(YourAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] navigationController]; //navigationController is a property in appDelegate
```

But more effective approach is to make [delegate method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html) inside your custom toolbar and then handle actions in target UIViewController.